# Issue in setting the attribute of an HTML element in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to change the data-theme attribute of a page(jQuery Mobile) dynamically so I bind an action to a button, this action gets the id of the page which I want to change it's 'data-theme' and then sets it's 'data-theme' to any swatch(a,b,c,d or e), when I press the button no theme change, here's the HTML:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="admin" data-theme="a" class="page">

    <div data-role="header">

    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content"> 
    <a href="#" id="themeButton" data-theme="b" data-role="button" data-inline="true" >ChangeTheme</a>
     </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="ew-footer" class="ui-splitview-hidden">

    </div><!-- /footer -->
  </div><!-- /page -->
```

here's my JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $('#admin').live('pageinit', function (event) {
        $('#themeButton').click(function () {

            document.getElementById('admin').setAttribute('data-theme', 'b')

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> document.getElementById('RemoveButton').setAttribute('data-theme','b')
> ```

Your markup has no element with the `id` value "RemoveButton", so that code is going to throw an exception, because `document.getElementById('RemoveButton')` will return `null`, which you're then trying to dereference.

---

Separately, as you're using jQuery already, why aren't you using it there? E.g.

```
$("#RemoveButton").attr("data-theme", "b");
```

That would at least prevent your getting an error, though of course it won't do anything (because, again, there's no element with that `id` in the markup you quoted).

Comment: sorry, i was intending the id of the page, but it was a mistake, now i correct it

Comment: i tried it  $("#RemoveButton").attr("data-theme", "b"); but it still doesn't change the page thme

Comment: @Eslam: I see you've changed your question, changing "RemoveButton" to "admin". Did `$("#admin").attr("data-theme", "b")` work?

Comment: no, it doesn't work, mainly (#admin) was my target, not(#RemoveButton) but it was a mistake

Comment: @Eslam: Don't know, then. Your original question was something I thought I could help with, but not if we get into jQuery Mobile-specific stuff. Good luck,